# I using OMDB API for getting movies, while parsing the Data in JSON format I am getting an error, though I am getting some JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

Its just simple api get request, and I've used other apis and it has worked fine previously, but I am facing this issue with this api. I am using nodejs, express, bodyparser and https node modeule.

```
    

          app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
                   const apiKey = "d996efb3";
                   const title = "martian";
                   const url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=" + apiKey + "&t=" + title;
    
                   https.get(url, function(response) {
                      console.log(response.statusCode);
    
                    response.on("data", function(data){
                    const movieData = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(movieData);
                 });
               });
    
      res.send("server is up and running");

})
```

This is the output I get after running the code in the terminal, I do get some data but not complete.

```
{"Title":"Martian","Year":"2015","Rated":"N/A","Released":"04 May 2015","Runtime":"7 min","Genre":"Animation, Short","Director":"Nils Skapans","Writer":"Nils Skapans","Actors":"N/A","Plot":"A boy wins a new toy in a claw machine - an ordinary Martian doll. It turns out that things are not that simple, the boy finds himself on Mars and he has to fight with a whole bunch of the Martians.","Language":"None","Country":"Latvia","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU3NDQyODgyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTgwODU2MDI@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database",



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pavan\Web Dev\movieApi\app.js:19:30)  
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:519:10)
    at flow (internal/streams/readable.js:992:34)
    at resume_ (internal/streams/readable.js:973:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: A `"data"` event does not mean that the response has been completely received. You have to accumulate the buffers and only parse when you get the `"end"` event.

Comment: I am still learning, can you elaborate it more clearly.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Comment: Thanks I found the solution!